# What is the scope in GitLab to let user only access to public repos with the oauth token?

Tags: oauth, gitlab

I have found the scope "read_repository" in the documentation, but I cannot find the scope that would only allow users read the public repositories belong to the access token owner. Is that feature available at the moment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the [GitLab Repository API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/repositories.html) is an endpoint which can be accessed *without* authentication *if the repository is publicly accessible*, ... it might not need a scope.

An [issue like 28324](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/28324) asks for read_repository PAT to be applicable Repository API, not just the [Repository files API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html), for example to access the file archive with a `read_repository` PAT from a *private* repository.

But for a public one, you would not need anything particular.